# Связка PHP и Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap, foreach, grid

Я вывожу по 10 результатов с запроса на страницу, и каждую отдельную статью заворачиваю в class col-lg-6 а все 10 записей заворачиваю в class row. В итоге получаю 2 колонки по 5 записей.

Выглядит это сейчас вот так:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но количество текста или размер изображения в записи не такое как у остальных, все верстка съезжает. Наверное все с таким сталкивались при верстке на bootstrap.

Задача:
Как найти первую и вторую запись и добавить им отрывающий тег с классом `<div class="col-lg-6">` а предпоследней и последней записи закрывающий тег `</div>`

На выходе хочу получить вот такую верстку:

```
<div class="row">
    <div classs="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 3</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 5</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 7</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 9</div>
    </div>
    <div classs="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 4</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 6</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 8</div>
        <div class="item">Содержимое 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: *вывожу по 10 результатов с запроса на страницу, и каждую отдельную статью заворачиваю в class col-lg-6 а все 10 записей заворачиваю в class row.* - код покажите

Comment: Обыкновенный цикл foreach и вывод через echo

Comment: то что вы спрашиваете - array_chunk и implode

Comment: Потрясающий комментарий! Помог

Comment: код покажите -  будет предмет